# How to create sub-enumerator with limited scope?

Tags: c#, ienumerator

Let's say I have collection with 100 elements. Regular enumerator would iterate over those 100 elements.

I would like to create enumerator (which is based on the regular enumerator, i.e. it is not per each collection, but rather one, general approach) which scope is from "hehe" to "there" -- and I could have for example iterate over 20 elements in the middle only.

```
void foo(IEnumerable<int> coll)
{
   var regular_iter = coll.GetEnumerator();
   regular_iter.MoveNext();
   regular_iter.MoveNext();
   // ... 8 more
   var scoped_iter = new ScopeEnumerator(regular_iterator,20);
```

So in such case when I call "scoped_iter.Reset()" it is reseted to its 0 element (10th for entire collection).

And also it "sees" only elements from 10-30.

**The question is** -- how to implement such enumerator?

### Edit

#### 1.

I need iterator from "here", not from "there", because getting to "there" could be very time consuming. However this is minor thing really, the most problematic is Reset method.

#### 2.

Jon asked about the background. What I really try to achieve is slicing the collection (i.e. you have the -- let's say -- collection of 10 strings, but you would like to interpret it as collection of 5 elements, each element being collection of 2 strings). Naive algorithm is pretty simple, but also is very inefficient. With collection ~16MB (list of strings) I though about another approach -- simply reinterpreting the data, without copying it. So I would create one iterator which picks every SIZE_OF_SLICE element from entire collection, and also I would create this scoped iterator which would start from the first iterator and go for SIZE_OF_SLICE elements.

This way data will be re-used in place, the only difference would be how you iterate over it. It is sufficient for slicing and it should be fast.

#### 3

I implemented efficient slicing for IList (once you assume you have indexer, it is piece of cake) but it is disturbing me, you cannot (?) provide general efficient algorithm for both list (LinkedList) and arrays (List). So if you are reading this, and have an idea how to do it, do not hestitate to answer, even after 10 years (assuming C# will be still with us).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with the minimum of effort, you'd basically populate a collection which *does* support `Reset` (e.g. `List<T>`) with the iterator, and then return that.

It's slightly trickier to do that *lazily* - i.e. the first time you iterate, populate a collection. After the first reset, go into "replay" mode. I'm sure it's feasible - it would just be slightly tricky.

It would be even trickier if you had to support being reset the first time after only (say) 15 elements, then when you hit the 16th element the second time round, going back to the original iterator. Yikes.

If you can scope out exactly what requirements you have, it could be a fun thing to implement though...

EDIT: Just to pull some of the comments into this answer: you can't do this *in general* without copying the data, because there's no guarantee that the iterator will support being reset at all. Imagine if the iterator is providing data from some random number generator, or it's a live broadcast which isn't being recorded - obviously to replay the data, *something* would have to copy it.

If you have a *particular source implementation* in mind, that may be different - but you can't do it through *just* the `IEnumerator<T>` interface.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't fully get it. When you write "populate a collection" you mean for scoped iterator? But this would also mean copying a lot of data, because you cannot guarantee in advance the the element of collection is just a class (for example). I have to just iterate, no data copying. It has to be as light as possible.

Comment: @macias: Then you're stuck. The original iterator may not support being reset, and even if did you wouldn't know its original position to skip to that when the scoped iterator is reset.

Comment: This is very sad news. It means that if you have 1T of data, and you would like to **view** it as 2D array, you would have to copy those 1T of data. Ouch! I wait a bit, maybe someone will come up with miracle-answer ;-) If not, your comment is the answer. *Sick SO -- I cannot start my comment with "@Jon" or "@Jon Skeet", you are not banned, aren't you? ;-)*.

Comment: @macias: If you have a very specific source type, you may well be able to sort it. But imagine if the data is being streamed from somewhere - there may be no concept of "reset". (Imagine it's a stream of random numbers.) So you can't do it *in general*.

Comment: I am not talking about streams, but collections -- arrays, lists, sets. I know that IEnumerable is a bit more, but I have solid data in mind. Even if it is random, it is already randomized, so each element is not changing any more.

Comment: @macias: Right, so as I said, with a specific source type in mind, you may be able to do it. But I wouldn't try to do it from a starting point of `IEnumerator<T>` - I'd create the "slice" from `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see much of the change. Since I don't modify a collection, the only useful part is getting enumerator. Which brings us back to writting enumerator.

Comment: @macias: No, there's a huge difference in what you can do with a collection: you can apply random access to it, so get back to wherever you are. Compare that with an iterator which *only* generally provides forward access, *sometimes* allowing a reset, but then only to the start. It has nothing to do with whether you're trying to modify the collection - it has everything to with how you can *access* the collection.

Comment: I still don't get the difference. The original collection is as it is (list, array, set), so when I build slices (each slice would be ICollection) on top of it I am limited to what the original collection provides, and the only interesting part is getting enumerator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx

Comment: @macias: Okay, if I give you an iterator already positioned on the 5th element, how do you give me the 6th element and then the 5th element again, without copying that 5th element? Now ask yourself the same question again when I give you a collection instead. You can't get back from an iterator to its source collection, at least without hacky reflection etc.

Comment: That's why I am wondering about copying enumerator (not data) :-) However I am not saying enumerator is "better", simply using ICollection instead does not help.

Comment: @macias: What do you even mean by "copying enumerator"? Given an enumerator, you simply can't get to arbitrary elements. Using `ICollection<T>` you can. So yes, using `ICollection<T>` *does* help. Heck, I can implement it for you with `ICollection<T>` - I can't for `IEnumerator<T>`.

Comment: Copying = when I do MoveNext in copy, the position of the original enumerator does not change. ICollection -- I really would like to see it, but I don't (remember: no data copying). The "Slice<T> : ICollection<T>" is really a view for original collection.

Comment: @macias: No, that's not true. `MoveNext()` mutates the iterator itself. Don't forget that `IEnumerator<T>` is an interface - copying the value will just copy a reference. I wasn't thinking of `Slice<T> : ICollection<T>`, but `Slice<T> : IEnumerable<T>` and *create* a `Slice<T>` from an `ICollection<T>`. If you're still interested in that, I'll code it up when I get time.

Comment: @macias: Gah - I was slightly off with my interfaces. I'd want `IList<T>` ideally, as *that's* what provides random access. That's still fine for arrays and lists - not sets, but then sets don't generally have an inherent order, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about taking a slice of them.

Comment: About MoveNext, yes I know, that's a pity I then cannot get real copy of enumerator. With such change, that the original collection is IList is easy, you simply get rid of enumerator, and use index to get base for slice, and offset within slice. Correct? I couldn't see it for something more general than IList.

Comment: @macias: Yes, that's right - because anything which *does* allow random access to the collection by position should be implementing `IList<T>` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To get an iterator that only sees elements 10-30, use `original.Skip(10).Take(20)`, although I don't think you can use `Reset` on it.

If you need to be able to reset it, just use something like

```
original.Skip(10).Take(20).ToArray()
```

Comment: A lot of iterators don't support `Reset`. It's only really there for compatibility with COM and shouldn't be relied on. The only reliable way to "reset" an iterator is to create a new one.

Comment: Indeed any iterator created with an iterator block can't be relied on.

Comment: @Sven, let's say I could create a new one, but how? I cannot re-iterate the original.